# Participle clause containing a subject

Tags: phrases, clauses, participles, participial-phrases

I am confused as to whether it is correct to use a participle clause as a nonessential element in a sentence like with a participle phrase.

For example, I know that the following sentence is correct:

> Knowing not to run, Harriet walked quickly down the aisle.

This is a participle *phrase* + independent clause.

However, I'm unsure if the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> Knowing she shouldn't run, Harriet walked quickly down the aisle.

The introductory element appears to be a *clause*, not a phrase, because it contains a subject (she) and a predicate (shouldn't run)

I would like to know whether I am correct in my analysis, and if so, whether it is grammatically correct; most websites refer to the use of nonessential participle phrases, not participle clauses.

Comment: Your second example is just a slightly extended "participle clause". Compare ***Sobbing**, Harriet walked quickly down the aisle*, where the continuous participle stands alone, And ***Crying her eyes out**, Harriet walked quickly down the aisle*, which is just a bit more complex.

Comment: ...I'd say your example includes an "implicit that- clause" - *Knowing **that** she shouldn't run...*

Comment: I agree. Is it gramatically correct to have a that-clause as part of a non-essential participle element?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking but... In traditional grammar terms, your first example shows a [reduced adverb clause](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-adverb-clauses-1211106). *Because she knew not to run* becomes *Knowing not to run*. Your second example does too — it just happens to also contain a zero *that* *that-clause*. Because she knew [that] she shouldn't run* becomes *Knowing she shouldn't run*. I don't think essential or nonessential is relevant here.

Comment: They are both participial clauses functioning as supplements, i.e. loosely attached elements set apart by punctuation presenting supplementary, non-integrated content. Note that in your second example the participial clause ("knowing ...") does not contain a subject. It's the embedded finite clause "(that) she shouldn't run" that contains a subject.